# why I can’t open a App Store link inside a web view?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, app-store

I'm getting always this error :

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102
```

Normal links are working but the AppStore one is not working

what I want is the Link to open the AppStore I can't do it locally because the web is loaded from a Qualtrics web.

I try it adding the navigationAction function but that doesn't work, what I'm guessing is that maybe the request is taking some time and i need a way of load that data on an async way but to be honest i really dont know

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let html = """


<a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/directorio-notarios-cdmx/id1544000342"> Appstore link dont open</a></span></span><br />

<a href="https://landercorp.mx" rel="noopener"> Normal link </a></span></span><br />
"""

    var loadStatusChanged: ((Bool, Error?) -> Void)? = nil

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let view = WKWebView()
        view.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        view.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        return view
    }



    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        
    }
}
 

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some links on tapping them might activate actions / redirect with url schemes that are non HTTPs like

- `_blank` to open a new tab
- `mailto` to launch the mail application
- some other deep link techniques familiar to device OSs

I believe the app store link uses a combination of the above and WKWebView cannot handle non HTTPs schemes.

What you can do is to listen to URLs that fail using `WKNavigationDelegate` and handle them accordingly

I am not using SwiftUI but I think you can get the picture.

Set up using the same HTML as you with both the links

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate
{
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let html = """
        <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/directorio-notarios-cdmx/id1544000342"> Appstore link dont open</a></span></span><br />

        <a href="https://landercorp.mx" rel="noopener"> Normal link </a></span></span><br />
        """
        
        let webview = WKWebView()
        webview.frame = view.bounds
        webview.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webview)
        webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Then I implement these `WKNavigationDelegate` functions

1. `decidePolicyFor navigationAction` [(documentation link)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview) to allow even urls that do not follow the HTTPs scheme to be allowed to be processed
2. this [navigation fail delegate function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455637-webview) `webView didFailProvisionalNavigation` and check if iOS can handle the open in a new tab, mail, deep link etc so in your case it would open the app store
3. You could also implement the same logic as point 2 in this
   [WKNavigationDelegate function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455623-webview?changes=_1__5) just in case

```
// MARK: WKNavigationDelegates

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
{
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
             withError error: Error)
{
    manageFailedNavigation(webView,
                           didFail: navigation,
                           withError: error)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             didFail navigation: WKNavigation!,
             withError error: Error)
{
    manageFailedNavigation(webView,
                           didFail: navigation,
                           withError: error)
}

private func manageFailedNavigation(_ webView: WKWebView,
                                    didFail navigation: WKNavigation!,
                                    withError error: Error)
{
    // Check if this failed because of mailto, _blank, deep links etc
    // I have commented out how to check for a specific case like open in a new tab,
    // you can try to handle each case as you wish
    if error.localizedDescription
        == "Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)"
       //let url = webView.url, url.description.lowercased().range(of: "blank") != nil
    {
        // Convert error to NSError so we can access the url
        let nsError = error as NSError
        
        // Get the url from the error
        // This key could change in future iOS releases
        if let failedURL = nsError.userInfo["NSErrorFailingURLKey"] as? URL
        {
            // Check if the action can be handled by iOS
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(failedURL)
            {
                // Request iOS to open handle the link
                UIApplication.shared.open(failedURL, options: [:],
                                          completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Give this a go and check if this fixes your issue. On my side, both links seem to work fine:

[image: Open WKWebview target="_blank" mailto deeplink new tab app store link or open an App Store link inside a web view]

Comment: Thank you! Yesterday I read all the stack overflow question related and couldn't fine some answers that helped me, this is not just a clear answer but a really complete one

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!

Comment: If you want to avoid tripping up by using the raw string there is a constant you can use: NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JamesWolfe , just to be clear, are you referring to replacing "NSErrorFailingURLKey" with NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey ?

Comment: I believe so :)